# Reusing OpenCV 2.3.1 bundled image Stitching module

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am lost in a rabbit hole, please bear with me.

I'm trying to use the OpenCV Stitching module from the 2.3.1 Win superpack distribution.   I dragged all the source files in /modules/stitching into a Visual Studio project, resolved the Includes and Libs as best I could, and got it to compile.*

The first strange runtime error I had was that I could not read a JPG file from disk with `imread()`. It did not throw an error, but was returning true for `myImage.empty()`. I reverted to `cvLoadImage()` and then it worked.

Now, after that, there is a new runtime error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00870d8f in MyStitcher.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x010e7000.

This occurs in /modules/stitching/matchers.cpp when trying to pass reference to `features.keypoints` as a `detector_->detect()` argument. I assume `detect()` is supposed to populate the keypoints with its result. `features` appears to be uninitialized (it has 612933850 empty keypoints at the breakpoint). Now this is starting to sound like the source I'm trying to compile is just broken, but opencv_stitching.exe that comes prebuilt works just fine. Was it compiled from different source?

By the way, I do not know how to use the CMake system to generate Visual Studio projects, as recommended, for OpenCV. The CMakeLists.txt file in the /modules/stitching folder did not work. Is it not supposed to be used as a starting point?

---

> *One note on this: CMakeLists.txt in /modules/stitching specifies some
>   libs named opencv_core, opencv_imgproc, opencv_highgui, etc. (without
>   a version indication) but the libs included with OpenCV 2.3.1 Win32
>   superpack (which I'm linking to) are named opencv_core231.lib,
>   opencv_imgproc231.lib, etc. Is this a clear indication that I am using
>   mismatched binaries for the stitching module?

Comment: Stitching is the newest and less stable OpenCV module. If you are going to try this module then I recommend you update your sources to the latest OpenCV trunk. Stitching in trunk is already slitted to dll and several samples. Also a lot of bugs are fixed.

Comment: Ok, interesting.  I am hopeful because it seems to produce great results. Today I downloaded current /modules/stitching from SVN and tried to link it with 2.3.1 libs. Obviously, this didn't work. :) I'll retrieve the whole trunk and post back here if I have any problems. Thanks Andrey.

Comment: By the way, if you have troubles building OpneCV from sources, you can check a [tuturial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#installation-by-making-your-own-libraries-from-the-source-files) from OpenCV documentation.

Comment: I have posted another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493159/what-do-the-optional-libraries-in-the-opencv-build-provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working after building the latest from the OpenCV SVN.  The stitching module came a long way since the 231 release.